# Sort with lambda in Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

This code works in Python 2.7, how can I do that work in Python 3?

```
arestas = dict()
edges = arestas.items()
edges.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

The error returned is:

AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

At issue here is that `dict.items()` returns a [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) in Python 3. It is as if you called [`dict.viewitems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems) in Python 2.

Either convert the dictionary view to a list first, or use the [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
edges = list(arestas.items())
edges.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

or

```
edges = arestas.items()
edges = sorted(edges, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Since the latter includes an implicit conversion to `list` anyway, it is the better choice unless you have a need to still access the unsorted list too.

Comment: "Unless you have a need to still access the unsorted list too." mind explaining this a little? How can you still access the unsorted list in either of your examples?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: `edges = list(arestas.items())` gives you that list; you could do things with it before sorting with either `edges.sort()` or `sorted(edges)`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just misunderstood the sentence. Alright, all cool :)